# Why does my delete button does not delete the card

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete the card when we click on the delete button after adding a TODO note
I have created a website which uses localstorage to store notes and display when clicking the create TODO button and it all works but when I click the delete button after the note is created (You have to create a TODO first) it does not delete the div itself 
I want to delete the card when we click on the delete button 
CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO List</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .main-title {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .input {
            border: 2px solid grey;
        }

        .all-todo {
            display: flex;
            margin: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TODO List</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="main-title">TODO List</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Task Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Task Details</label>
            <textarea class="form-control input" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="main-btn">Create TODO</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="clr">Clear LocalStorage</button>
    </div>
    <div class="all-todo"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script>
    let button = document.getElementById("main-btn")

    button.onclick = () => {
        let key = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlInput1").value
        let value = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1").value
        if (key != "" && value != "") {
            iHTML = ""
            localStorage.setItem(key, value)
            iHTML += `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${key}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${localStorage.getItem(key)}</p>
                    <button type="button" id="note" onclick='${key}.innerHTML=""' class="btn btn-danger '${key}'">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
            document.getElementsByClassName("all-todo")[0].innerHTML += iHTML
        }
        else {
            alert("Task Name or Details cannot be empty!")
        }

    }

    let clr_btn = document.getElementById("clr")
    clr_btn.onclick = () => {
        localStorage.clear()
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown on this line `onclick='${key}.innerHTML=""'`. You will want to first remove the item from local storage e.g: `localStorage.removeItem('${key}')` and then remove the html. Theres many way of achieveing this but `this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()` should be sufficient

The complete button should look something like `<button type="button" id="note" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('${key}'); this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()" class="btn btn-danger '${key}'">Delete</button>`

Heres a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qt83bshd/

Answer (score 1):

Well, i post you a simple solution for your problem.
Instead of use innerhtml to introuce your todos, yo can create the elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO List</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .main-title {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .input {
            border: 2px solid grey;
        }

        .all-todo {
            display: flex;
            margin: 30px;
        }
        /* add css in this poiint to optimize code*/
        .card {
            width: 18rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TODO List</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="main-title">TODO List</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Task Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Task Details</label>
            <textarea class="form-control input" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="main-btn">Create TODO</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="clr">Clear LocalStorage</button>
    </div>
    <div class="all-todo"></div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script>
    let button = document.getElementById("main-btn")

    button.onclick = () => {
        // collect the div that contains all the todos
        let alltodo = document.querySelector(".all-todo");

        let key = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlInput1").value
        let value = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1").value

        // and if it any todo create the card
        if (key != "" && value != "") {

            localStorage.setItem(key, value)
            // with create element we can create the card more easy
            var todo = document.createElement("div");
            todo.setAttribute("class", "card");


            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.textContent = "eliminar";


            var titulo = document.createElement("h5");

            titulo.textContent = key;

            button.onclick = () => {
                console.log(button.parentElement.remove())
                // in this point we can also remove the todo from the local storage wih localstorage.removeItem()
            }

            // introduce all items in dom 
            todo.appendChild(titulo)
            todo.appendChild(button);
            alltodo.appendChild(todo);
            // iHTML = ""
            // localStorage.setItem(key, value)
            // iHTML += `
            // <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            //     <div class="card-body">
            //         <h5 class="card-title">${key}</h5>
            //         <p class="card-text">${localStorage.getItem(key)}</p>
            //         <button type="button" id="note" onclick='${key}.innerHTML=""' class="btn btn-danger '${key}'">Delete</button>
            //     </div>
            // </div>
            // `
            // document.getElementsByClassName("all-todo")[0].innerHTML += iHTML
            
        }
        else {
            alert("Task Name or Details cannot be empty!")
        }

    }

    let clr_btn = document.getElementById("clr")
    clr_btn.onclick = () => {
        localStorage.clear()
    }

</script>

</html>
```